# Sum values in df column based on partial name of another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given the dataframe

```
a       b
foo123  5
foo456  8
bar234  1
bar324  6
```

How do I add the values from b based on the only the first several characters of a? The ouput I'm looking for is:

```
a    b
foo  13
bar  7
```

There are too many entries for column `a` to set manually, so something like the following won't work:

```
if df['a'].startswith('foo'):
    sum(b)
```

I'm thinking something more like if `df['a']` has first three characters that match, add all the corresponding rows for `b`.

Answer (score 4):

If your substrings do not all have the same length, use `str.extract`, extract relevant portions from `a` and then use that to perform a `groupby` + `sum` operation on `b`:

```
# assuming your frame is df1
df1.groupby(df1['a'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False))['b'].sum().reset_index()

     a   b
0  bar   7
1  foo  13
```

For more performance, pre-assign `a` first;

```
df1['a'] = df1['a'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False)
df1.groupby('a', as_index=False)['b'].sum()

     a   b
0  bar   7
1  foo  13
```

---

If all substrings are of the same size, just slice and `groupby`:

```
df1.groupby(df1['a'].str[:3])['b'].sum().reset_index()

     a   b
0  bar   7
1  foo  13
```

Comment: Using `df.a.str.extract(r'^(\D+)'...` only gives me the first two letters of column a. Using `df.groupby(df.a.str[:3])...` gives me the error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'`. I should've given a better sample df, my actual df has full column names (e.g. `sample` and `counts`), so this might be the source of the error? (I am changing `a` and `b` from your example into `sample` and `counts`.)

Comment: @Liquidity Hmm, use `df['sample']` because `sample` is a dataframe method, so you can't use the `.` accessor there. Also, the "first two letters" is a consequence of the way you formulated your problem in your original question. If you have any other concerns, you really should have your [mcve] reflect those.

Comment: Also my fault, say my `df` is actually called `df1`. Where do I replace `df` with `df1`? I've tried many combinations, but it seems like there are places where you just leave the generic `df` and I can't find them.

Comment: @Liquidity I've edited my answer, I hope things are clearer now. There's nothing called a "generic" `df`, that's just the convention used for naming dataframe variables.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Using either option works, but turns my entire `sample` column to NaN. Any ideas? Thanks for updating your original answer, that helped my understanding a lot. :)

Comment: @Liquidity I can't imagine why that is. Except for option 1b, none of my options modify your original dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` number to ''

```
df.groupby(df.a.str.replace('\d+', '')).b.sum()
Out[1353]: 
a
bar     7
foo    13
Name: b, dtype: int64
```